# CodeIgniter how to save token received from REST API

Tags: php, rest, api, codeigniter, token

I looked but I can't find the answer to this. 
I am building CodeIgniter app that uses data from `REST API` in `JSON`. `guzzlehttp` delivers token after login. Works like charm.

The only problem is that there is no way to store the token into local storage so it can be used for subsequent requests or later visits. Even if I store token in the `SESSION`, it will not be available once the user closes the browser and then comes back to the app.

Is there a way to use "localStorage.setItem('token', $token)"
or something similar?

Comment: Why did you tag this as PHP? This sounds purely client side. You'll likely use javascript to store the token into the users local/session storage, and check that storage to see if the token exists / is valid before using it

Comment: Use a persistent cookie.